# print long text coming from excel

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl

I am trying to print a text field with a line break because it is too long, but something is not working. I send the text from an Excel database connection.

```
^XA
^FOx,y
^A0N,8,24
^FB40,4,0,L
^FD\&^FS
^XZ
```

Comment: Need to see the full ZPL.  What you have posted doesn't make a lot of sense...

Comment: Thank you Mark.
I am following the instructions found at the following link:  
that is the code I have copied into my printer properties.

Comment: https://supportcommunity.zebra.com/s/article/Creating-a-ZebraDesigner-Field-that-will-wrap-text?language=es_MX

Comment: Please add more details on you are expecting to use this. What software you are using, where you entered this ZPL, etc..